# Remove gap between widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to close the gap between the lists but its just not working. the only option i have is to increase the gap : Sizedbox,spacer,divider

[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMJ4X.png)

code:

```js
body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _mainList(Icon(Icons.cached), "Erste", "21:13 pm"),
            _mainList(Icon(Icons.cached), "Zweite", "21:13 pm"),
            _mainList(Icon(Icons.cached), "Dritte", "21:13 pm"),
            _mainList(Icon(Icons.cached), "Vierte", "21:13 pm"),
          ]
        )
  )
```

```js
  Widget _mainList(Icon symbol, String name, String time){
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: symbol,
        title: Text(name, textScaleFactor: 1.2),
        trailing: Text(time, textScaleFactor: 1.3),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Try changing the Padding value from `EdgeInsets.symmetric` to `EdgeInsets.only(top : value, )`

Comment: i tried it. it will make the texts spread to left and right. but the gap between the next line remains the same.

Comment: It's because you are using ListTitle. ListTile has a padding of its own. Which I think cannot be overridden. you can try either changing the value to the file itself or work with Rows or something of your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a fix (kinda). just add:

dense: true

inside ListTile() it will reduce the gap a bit but thats all i can do for now. I'll keep looking for a better solution if anyone has any.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> _names = ["Erste","Zweite","Dritte","Vierte"];
  final List<String> _dates = ["21:13 pm","21:13 pm","21:13 pm","21:13 pm"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:0.0),
            title: Text(_names[index]),
            leading: Icon(Icons.cached),
            trailing: Text(_dates[index]),
            );
          }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `ListTile` has it's own `Padding`. You can try changing the `Padding` of the `ListTile`. And if it's still not enough you should create your own `Widget` without vertical padding

You can always go to the source code of `ListTile` and copy and customize it.

Answer (score 0):

`contentPadding` of `ListTile` is `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)` by default. So it has padding from top and bottom. You can change it like following:

```
ListTile(
  // I made zero padding for this example but you can give anything you want
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  leading: symbol,
  title: Text(name, textScaleFactor: 1.2),
  trailing: Text(time, textScaleFactor: 1.3),
)
```

Comment: still not working. this adjusts to left and right but not between the lists

Comment: Also `Icons` have default size value which is 24. Even if you make padding zero, size of your `ListTile` will be 24 to fit Icon inside it. So you can change the size of your icons. Ex: `Icon(Icons.cached, size: 16)`

Comment: i changed the icon size to the smallest but still no success :(

Comment: @Domi You won't be able to achieve what you want whit ListTile. Make your own widget